# Sub-classes, assignment operator overloading?

Tags: c++, subclass

If I have the given below classes:

```
class TestA
{
    public:
        const TestA &operator=(const int A){return *this;}
};

class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        //Inheritance?
};
```

The question presumes both class TestA and class TestB have exactly the same contents in terms of variables: Is the assignment operator (or any other operator) inherited?

Is the following valid?

```
class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        using TestA::operator=;
        //Inheritance?
};
```

If it is valid, would it make a difference?

Comment: Just as a note: `operator=` should return a non-`const` reference to `this`

Comment: @king_nak It can return whatever it wants -- even `void` (however if you want to chain assignment operations as in `a = b = c` it should return non-const reference).

Comment: @Alex If it has to take a const, returning const would make no difference to chain as it's right to left.

Comment: @Alex & Sight As overloaded operators _should_ behave like on POD, the return value _should_ be a non-`const` reference. Chaining will work with a `const` reference, but not the statement `(a = b) = c;`, which works on POD. But that's a very special case...

Comment: @king_nak "Morally" it *should* behave like on POD, by "legally" it can return anything. I'm talking about "legality" issue. From "morality" perspective it should also accept not `int` but const ref parameter.

Comment: @Alex There might be also situations where other parameters are "morally" acceptable (as int is also assignable to float...). E.g. a time wrapper class where you can assign a long like `time()` returns. But generally, the golden rule is to not astonish user of your class and do unexpected things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment operators are **hidden** by derived class by default (as compiler always generates a `T& operator = ()` for any `class T`, if not specified). Which makes the inherited `operator =` not usable.

**Yes** when you specify them with `using` keyword; they become **usable**. [Demo](http://www.ideone.com/baGH8). So your code snippet does make sense.

```
public: using TestA::operator=;
```

Comment: The methods specified with `using` have the visibility of where you put the using. So if it's before the `public:`, they're private... With this you can change the visibility of inherited methods

Comment: This is what I was hoping for! Thank you iammilind!

Comment: @king_nak, yes you are correct. I was thinking till now that `using` is also same as `friend`; put it anywhere irrespective of specifier.

Comment: @Alf: please elaborate. do you mean it's inherited but hidden by auto-generated default `operator=(TestB const&)`? isn't this the same?

Comment: @Andy T, you are correct. Theoretically they are inherited however they are not usable due to hiding.

Comment: @Alf, spirit is when you really upvote and not just almost. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The question's example code as I'm writing this:

```
class TestA
{
    public:
        const TestA &operator=(const int A){return *this;}
};

class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        //Inheritance?
};
```

#### Q1: "Is the assignment operator (or any other operator) inherited?"

Yes, of course. The only member functions that are not inherited in C++98, are constructors. However, the base class implementations are by default **hidden** by the automatically generated *copy assignment* operator. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TestA
{
    public:
        TestA const& operator=( int const )
        {
            cout << "TestA = int" << endl;
            return *this;
        }
};

class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        // Automatically generated copy assignment operator.
};

int main()
{
    TestB   o;

    cout << "Calling automatically generated copy assignment:" << endl;
    cout << "(should be nothing here ->) ";  o = TestB();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Calling base class assignment operator:" << endl;
    // o = 42;     // won't compile, because it's hidden.
    cout << "(should be output here ->) ";  o.TestA::operator=( 42 );   // OK.
    cout << endl;
}
```

Considering all the answers so far that have confused hiding and inheritance, and just to clear up the terminology here, N3290 (which is identical to C++11 standard), says this:

> **N3290 §10/2:**
>   "Inherited members can be referred to in expressions in the same manner
>   as other members of the derived class, unless their names are hidden or ambiguous"

In the example code above `TestA::operator=` is hidden, but see the answer to Q3.

#### Q2: Is the following valid?

This question refers to use of `using` in the derived class, like

```
class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        using TestA::operator=;
        //Inheritance?
};
```

Yes, that is valid.

It would not be valid in C++98 for a constructor, because constructors are not inherited.

#### Q3: If it is valid, would it make a difference?

Yes, it makes the base class assignment operator(s) directly accessible in the derived class.

For example, you can then remove the out-commenting in the example above,

```
// o = 42;     // won't compile, because it's hidden.
```

and it will still compile,

```
o = 42;        // compiles fine with "using".
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Alf got the right answer now but I am still a bit confused by last sentence from standard I was quating: "the operator introduced by the using-declaration is hidden by the implicitly-declared operator in the derived class." see my answer above for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the more in-depth answer. All the information is appreciated.

Comment: @Alf: Q2, agreed, but I would recommend to avoid it as much as possible because a) for slicing, even if ATM nothing is sliced; b) it cannot be used in sequence, e.g. `TestB t1, t2; t1 = t2 = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

I have found some related answer from C++ 11 standard :

**12.8 Copying and moving class objects**

Because a copy/move assignment operator is implicitly declared for a class if not declared by the user, a base class copy/move assignment operator is always hidden by the corresponding assignment operator of a derived class (13.5.3). A using-declaration (7.3.3) that brings in from a base class an assignment operator with a parameter type that could be that of a copy/move assignment operator for the derived class is not considered an explicit declaration of such an operator and does not suppress the implicit declaration of the derived class operator; the operator introduced by the using-declaration is hidden by the implicitly-declared operator in the derived class.

Comment: Thank you. I usually like to hear views on stack overflow as they offer insights and considerations I don't normally think of.

Comment: The assignment operator is just a (special) member function, and is inherited. It is however, by default, hidden by an automatically generated one.

Comment: However , I am a bit confused by last sentence from standard: the operator introduced by the using-declaration is hidden by the implicitly-declared operator in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment operator isn't inherited by derived.  If you use your overloaded assignment operator in your derived, from your base, you might encounter slicing: `sizeof(base) != sizeof(derived)`

Comment: I believe it would be still called "slicing" even if `sizeof(base) != sizeof(derived)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. So if the classes have the same variables, would slicing occur?

Comment: @SSight: you will encounter slicing anytime the type of the object passed in is of a type derived from `base` that has its own data members.

Comment: Even if there is no new data members in derived class, it is still *slicing*: the object of derived class is "sliced" and subobject of base class is returned. Would be disastrous if i.e. base has virtual functions which derived overrides.

Comment: @Alex Information like that is one of the reasons I post questions at stack overflow. I will probably need to start another question based on what you are saying.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't understand why that would be disastrous. If the inherited copy ctor calls any virtual functions during the copy they will still be called polymorphically. Yes, technically its still *slicing*, except nothing is being sliced.

Comment: @Fernanders it was general statement about what slicing it and whether it is related to additional member variables in derived class. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: "Yes, technically its still slicing, except nothing is being sliced." -- that was my point.

Comment: To clarify, @Alf comment,Assignment operator is also inherited by the derived class, the compiler generates an assignment operator by default for every class, and the one generated for derived class *hides* the base class inherited version of assignment operator.

Comment: Err..Sorry I didn't see Alf's explanation on other comments :(